# Sick [with/by] dengue

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct for this meaning(that the disease that "attacked" me was dengue)
▪︎ I tell my friend what the disease "attacked" me is by saying this, "I was sick [with/by] dengue."
I think "with" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition is "with".  While Dengue is rare, the same sense is used in "sick with flu".  This ngrams [shows the relative proportions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick%20with%20dengue%2Csick%20by%20dengue%2Csick%20with%20flu%2C%20sick%20by%20dengue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Note that "sick by (flu|dengue)" does not feature in the corpus at all.

Shorter, and with the same meaning is "I had dengue."

Comment: We usually say, "The flu."